# How to find all jobs which are using particular repository url in jenkins using groovy and disable them

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Want to develop some groovy script to find all jobs which are using some particular repository url( xxxx.com) and disable them. I am able to do this by below script which is not working for jobs which are under folders and subfolders.

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(hudson.model.AbstractProject.class).each {it ->
  scm = it.getScm()
  if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM)
  {
     if(scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl().contains('XXXXXXXX'))
     {
        println scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
        println it.name
        it.makeDisabled(true)
      }
  }
}
println "Done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is using [getAllItems](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Items.html#getAllItems-hudson.model.ItemGroup-java.lang.Class-) :

> Gets all the Items recursively in the ItemGroup tree and filter them  by the given type.

But a folder: `com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder` is class: `hudson.model.AbstractItem`, not `hudson.model.AbstractProject`. Use [alltems](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Items.html#allItems-hudson.model.ItemGroup-java.lang.Class-):

> Gets a read-only view of all the Items recursively matching type and
>   predicate in the ItemGroup tree visible to Jenkins.getAuthentication()
>   without concern for the order in which items are returned.
>   (The "order" being usually in reverse - ie: LIFO).

`Jenkins.instance.allItems(hudson.model.AbstractProject.class).each {it ->
    scm = it.getScm()
    if(scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
        if(scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()) {
            println it.fullName + ' - '+ scm.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
        }
    }
}
return`

or

`Jenkins.instance.allItems.findAll {
  it instanceof hudson.model.AbstractProject
}.each`

which will process them in alphabetical order (ie: FIFO).

`fullName` also gives you the folder path to the job; handy when traversing folders.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the above solution, is not getting  URLs for multibranch jobs (workflow)

Comment: You did not mention multibranch, did you? They are type `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, can you please guide how to do for multibranch jobs also.

Comment: Try replacing `hudson.model.AbstractProject.class`with `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class`?

Comment: After replacing the above class i am getting below errors.
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.getScm() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getSCMs(), getACL(), getACL(), getACL(), getApi(), getName()

Comment: Add `import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob` to the top.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the support. Posting the final script which is working for me .

Comment: Would you be so kind as to mark as answered as noted. Mine answers the posted question. If you mark yours as answered, you should edit the question to include the added details you provided in the comments (I could have provided a complete answer if those had been included to start).

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.jvnet.hudson.plugins.shelveproject.ShelveProjectTask
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob;
Jenkins.instance.allItems(org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob.class).each {it ->
scm = it.getSCMs()
for ( sc in scm ){

if ( sc instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM){

scurl = sc.getUserRemoteConfigs()[0].getUrl()
if ( scurl.contains('xxxxxxxxx') ){

println scurl
println it.getFullName()
// it.makeDisabled(true)
def spt=  new ShelveProjectTask(it)
Hudson.getInstance().getQueue().schedule(spt , 0 );
}}}
}
return
```